# MacBook Pro that runs Snow Leopard

Tags: macbook-pro

I want a MacBook Pro that runs Snow Leopard.  I think I need an early 2011 MacBook Pro to be able to run Snow Leopard. Where can I get a new or refurbished early 2011 MacBook Pro.  I don't think a later model will allow Snow Leopard to be installed.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is akeing where to get something

Answer (score 1):

Apple lists all software versions that run on models here:

- [Mac OS X versions (builds) for computers - http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1159](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1159)

So you could focus on models that shipped with Snow Leopard and perhaps look at even older models that meet the minimum system requirements for Snow Leopard.

- [Mac OS X v10.6 Snow Leopard - Technical Specifications  - http://support.apple.com/kb/SP575](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP575)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the Apple pages that bmike has mentioned, you can use Ian Page’s free [Mactracker](http://mactracker.ca) application to see both the earliest and the latest operating systems that every Macintosh model can run.

Mactracker confirms that the MacBook Pro (17-inch, Early 2011) is the last MacBook Pro that came with Mac OS X 10.6.x “Snow Leopard”, and that *all* MacBook Pros previous to that one can also run it out of the box.